# SWIFT CoreData NSManagedObject

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have a Custom NSManagedObject (in Swift) and looks like this

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

@objc(Item)
class Item: NSManagedObject {

@NSManaged var title:String

func entityName() -> String{
    println("Entity Name")
    let item = "Item"
    return item
}

func insertItemWithTitle (title: String? , managedObjectContext:NSManagedObjectContext) -> Item{
    println(title)
    let item = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(entityName(), inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as Item
    if title {
        item.title = title!
    }
    return item
}
```

}

What is The proper way to Initialize something like this and use it

Answer (score 1):

Instantiation (e.g. `init`) is taken care of by Core Data, so a class factory method is recommended for what you want to do.  For example:

```
@objc(Item)
class Item: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var title:String

    class func entityName() -> String {
        return "Item"
    }

    class func insertItemWithTitle(title: String, managedObjectContext:NSManagedObjectContext) -> Item {
        let item = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(Item.entityName(), inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! Item
        item.title = title
        return item
    }
}
```

You might also make parameter `title` NOT optional since the managed attribute `title` is required.  Or, you can make `title` optional, but make sure your model is updated to reflect this change.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm. How about

```
var item = Item.insertItemWithTitle(title:"Item Title", context)
item.entityName()
```