# Swift NSManagedObject factory

Tags: ios, core-data, swift2

I'm newish to Swift 2.0 and new to Core Data.

**I'm looking to "un-flatten" an assortment of Core Data `NSManagedObject`s. Right now, I'm using predicates and joining on a property, "parentNameID" and "nameID". I do have itemCategory and itemCategoryChildren relationships set up in the Core Data GUI, and I'd like to move toward joining on this relationship rather than a "flat" join via parentNameID<->>nameID and predicates. I suspect I'm really close but my `fetchedResultsParentID` container is always empty.**

Please don't direct me to SuperAwesomeAPI or StudlyGreatAPI; I'm looking to do this via native Core Data calls. I saw what could have been a discussion of great value get killed by an off-hand mention of an external API used.

I'm trying to **convert a class of mine with a factory method--`enumerate()`--to Core Data**. The `enumerate()` call works as expected--returns an array of class objects--when my class is of `NSObject`--but I can't seem to "un-flatten" the assortment of `NSManagedObject`s into a full Core Data relationship.

**What I have:** A class of Items (NSObject) and a factory class function, `enumerate()`, that returns an array of Items.

**What I'd like:** A class of Items (NSManagedObject) and a factory class function, enumerate(), that returns NSManagedObjects.

**What I've done:** Within `enumerate()` there are item properties being set, and an array of these items being generated. I'm calling `enumerate()` externally, from the `AppDelegate.Swift` file: `var items = Item.enumerate()` and then was setting properties on an NSManagedObject via `setValue()`.

I've looked at all sorts of answers, and the only thing I could really find that talked about a factory and Core Data was [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24792372/swift-coredata-nsmanagedobject).

I'm certainly not above fetching these items from a JSON or XML file, and will likely move that way in future, but this seems harder than a factory class making an array. If not, please let me know!!

Related `AppDelegate.Swift` function:

```
func preloadData(EntityName: String) {
    // Remove any data that may exist
    removeData(EntityName)

    var items = AllItems.enumerate()

    print("Array enumerated with \(items.count) items.")

    for item in items {
        let newItem = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(EntityName, inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as NSManagedObject
        // Required
        newItem.setValue(item.isCategory, forKey: "isCategory")
        newItem.setValue(item.name, forKey: "name")
        newItem.setValue(item.shortDetail, forKey: "shortDetail")
        newItem.setValue(item.itemID, forKey: "itemID")

        if (item.parentItemID != nil) {
            let fetchRequestParentID = NSFetchRequest(entityName:EntityName)
            let predicateParentID = NSPredicate(format: "parentItemID == %i", item.parentItemID!)
            fetchRequestParentID.predicate = predicateParentID
            do {
                let fetchedResultsParentID = try managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequestParentID) as? [NSManagedObject]
                // success ...
                // THIS IS WHERE THINGS FAIL.
                //                    newItem.setValue(fetchedResultsParentID, forKey: "itemCategory")
                newItem.setValue(fetchedResultsParentID, forKeyPath: "itemCategory")
            } catch let error as NSError {
                // failure
                print("Fetch failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }

                //                let fetchRequestParentID = NSFetchRequest(entityName: EntityName)
                //                fetchRequestParentID.fetchLimit = 1
                //                
                //                let fetchedEntitiesParentID = self.managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequestParentID)
                //                
                //                newItem.setValue(newItem, forKey: "itemCategory")
        }
    }

    items.removeAll()

    do {
        try managedObjectContext.save()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the `itemCategory` relationship is reflexive, i.e. from your entity to itself, with `itemCategoryChildren` as its inverse, and that it is many-one (each object has only one `itemCategory`, but can have many `itemCategoryChildren`).

Your predicate seems to be trying to fetch items with `parentItemID` that match the `parentItemID` of your `newItem`.  But

a) you never set the `parentItemID` attribute, so nothing will ever match; hence your empty results.

b) I suspect you actually want to fetch items with `itemID` that match `parentItemID` (..."a 'flat' join via parentNameID<->>nameID"):

```
let predicateParentID = NSPredicate(format: "itemID == %i", item.parentItemID!)
```

c) the results of the fetch will be an array, so when setting the relationship you need to extract the item from the array:

```
let parentItem = fetchedResultsParentID[0]
newItem.setValue(parentItem, forKeyPath: "itemCategory")
```

(Note also that when setting the relationship, you use the NSManagedObject itself, not the associated ID).

d) Another problem is that you might load a child before its parent.  So in fact it might be better to load all the items, then iterate through and make the relationships.

Comment: Hello. I'm just getting back to this. Thank you for taking the time to answer! A few things to start with: 

(b) is absolutely correct. I'm used to RDBMS work, so what I've built here is a two-way linked-list using an array of nodes. Correspondingly, you're right: each node has the relationship setup you describe.

(d) is a good point; my factory class is precise about load-order, but I was starting to wonder if I'd have to take the performance hit of first creating a bunch of NSManagedObject nodes, then establishing their relationship. 

I'll let you know about (a) and (c)! I'll be back.

Comment: Hmm. I remember seeing this error last night. 

`let parentItem = fetchedResultsParentID[0]` yields the failure "result type 'Element' does not match expected type."

**I know things can die quietly on the Internet, so I wanted to come back specifically and thank you.**

I read up a bit about NSSet. This led me to see that NSSet->Array conversion is possible via `.allObjects`. For anyone else struggling, here's an example from my viewController: 

`items = parentItem!.valueForKeyPath("itemCategoryChildren")?.allObjects as! [Item]`